# How do I implement something like pointers in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I know that javascript doesn't have pointers in terms of a variable referring to a place in memory but what I have is a number of variables which are subject to change and dependent on each other.

For example:

```
Center (x,y) = (offsetLeft + width/scale , offsetTop + height/scale)
```

As of now I have rewritten the equation in terms of each individual variable and after any changes I call the appropriate update function.

For example:
If scale changes, then then the center, height, and width stay the same. So I call

```
updateoffset() {
    offsetLeft = centerx - width/scale;
    offsetTop  = centery - height/scale;
}
```

Is this the easiest way to update each of these variables when any of them changes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I read your question in two different ways, so two answers:

#### Updating calculated values when other values change

The two usual ways are: 1. To require that the values only be changed via "setter" functions, and then you use that as an opportunity to recalcuate the things that changed, or 2. To require that you use "getter" functions to *get* the calculated value, which you calculate on the fly (or if that's expensive, you retrieve from a cached calculation).

#### Returning multiple values from a function

If you're looking for a way of returning multiple values from a single function, you can do that easily by returning an object. Example:

```
// Definition:
function center(offsetLeft, offsetTop, width, height, scale) {
    return {
        x: offsetLeft + width/scale,
        y: offsetTop + height/scale
    };
}

// Use:
var pos = center(100, 120, 10, 20, 2);
// pos.x is now 105
// pos.y is now 130
```

Comment: Ok, so essentially I am doing it the best way? Because each variable can change and depending on which variable is changing determines which variable/s remains constant and which needs to be updated.

It seemed repetitive, but it does make sense that this is the only real way that I could do it.

Comment: @Shaun: Yeah, I don't think there's much else you can do. When `width` changes, you may need to recalculate `x`; when `height` changes you don't, just `y`, etc. So it'll be a matter of either setters or getters doing the appropriate recalc to what's being set or gotten. But I'd encapsulate it in a reusable object.

Comment: For my particular case the reason that I have grouped them together is that if the center x (cx) or cy chages or as you said the width or height changes I am going ahead and updating both (It is very rare for only one to change anyway). 
I think another important thing that I forgot to mention is that all these varibales share the same scope. For that reason I don't pass/return them, I just change a variable and then call call the appropriate update function. Thanks again for the help